# "stap my vittles"

Tags: etymology, slang

Does anyone know the expression "stap my vittles"? I take it to mean just "holy smokes" (etc.), but I can't remember where I ever encountered it, nor can I find an explanation of the expression or even the word "stap."

Comment: If I type into Google `stap my vi` then the phrase is autocompleted to `stap my vitals` and there are [lots of results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stap+my+vitals).

Comment: @AndrewLeach promotion to ELL mod in chief!

Comment: Ah!! Many thanks! That should have occurred to me and didn't, since I was only thinking of "vittles" as "victuals."